# how to make a website go to full width and height in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am trying to understand how to make a web page which will go in full height and width in asp.net. I know to use width: 100% for the background but I am not understanding how to change the width and height of other buttons, , and other stuff..

I search on google and youtube for that but I am not getting a good tutorial to explain how I should make it.

Should I use jquery or javascript? I'm trying to stay far from those at the moment.

Can any one please give me a simple explanation about this?

Comment: Give me your HTML example, and wich element that you want to set width 100%, and wich element that you don't want set 100%

Comment: can you explain a little better please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to control ui styles, should be CSS.

For example, setting a element to full width and height

```css
.full_width {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  }

.element_inside {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button_inside {
  width: 125px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full_width">
  I am full width element
  
  <div class="element_inside">
    Low width
  </div>
  
  <button class="button_inside">
    Button
  </button>
  
  <button style="width: 100%;">
    Button full width
  </button>
</div>
```

But it uses absolute position.

You could use something like this too.

```css
html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table-row;
}

.full_width {
  width: 250px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.full_width {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="full_width">
  full width container
</div>
```

For responsive layout, and different screen different size, you can use following codes:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 740px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 960px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1160px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: SCREEN_WIDTH_IN_PIXELS) {
   .container { // my element width for this screen
        width: 1160px;
   }
}
```

Comment: that gave me a good idea of what to do. But what about when the page is bigger? the buttons height and width will increase/decrease? I mean, I got a 24' screen. and if the page is loaded in a 32' or bigger or smaller the page will show the design as it is designed for 24'?

Comment: Yes, it's `css` and it should be in css sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use different css container class for buttons. For ex;

```
.body{
width: 100%
}

button {
color: #666;
border-color: #EBEBEB;
background-color: #EBEBEB;
text-align: center;
height:200px;
width:200px;
}
```

And then use for button,

```
<button class="button">Button</button>
```